# Java - dom4j XPath for children nodes

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax, dom4j

I am using `[dom4j]`[1](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html) and `[XPath]`[2](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html#Pages~List_of_XPaths) in order to traverse an XML.

Assume I have in hand a `Node` which has children nodes, each of which has the same tag name. e.g. (refer to the `b` node):

```
<a>
    <b>...</b>
    <b>...</b>
</a>
```

I tried to use `selectNodes("//b")` but it returns all of the nodes within the **document** which their open tag is `b`.

How can I traverse only the children nodes of a specific node, where all the children nodes have the same tag name (e.g. `b`).

Answer (score 6):

```
selectNodes(".//b") 
//-----------^
```

The `.` is the current node in XPath.

Note that `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. This means it will also select nested nodes.

You speak of children, which is not the same thing. For child nodes use:

```
selectNodes("./b")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `selectNodes("a//b"`) if you want all `<b>` elements, no matter if they are children or children of children.  If you want only the `<b>` elements that are children of `<a>` use `selectNodes("a/b")`.

If you know that node `<a>` will be a child of the root node, you can add a / in front to denote that you're only selecting children of the root node like so: `selectNodes("/a//b")`

See the [xpath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) for more information

Answer (score 0):

you could use like this

```
//a/b
```

and `a` can be your specific node.